# Pass output from a function as input in another function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, input, output

How can one pass output from a function as an input in another function.

For example I have those two functions

```
collatz :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
collatz 1 = [1]  
collatz n  
    |even n = n:collatz (n `div` 2)  
    |odd n = n:collatz (n*3 + 1)
```

And my another function

```
length' [] = 0
length' (x:xs) = 1 + length' xs
```

I want to calculate the length of a list, which was output from my collatz function.

finally I want calculate completely this

```
numLongChains :: Int  
numLongChains = length (filter isLong (map collatz [1..100]))  
    where isLong xs = length xs > 15
```

But step by step.

Comment: What is `chain`? What does `numLongChains` have to do with calculating the length of a list outputted from your collatz function? It seems like you are describing two different questions. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: Ach sorry it is a mistake my chain  is my collatz function. I corrected ready. First I want to calculate length of output form a collanz function.

Comment: I don't understand. What don't you like about the code you already have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about [function composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition):

```
-- assuming signature length' :: [a] -> Int   
composed :: (Integral a) => a -> Int
composed = length' . collatz
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'step by step', but for your second question, it would be:

```
numLongChains :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Int
numLongChains = length' . (filter isLong) . (map collatz)
    where isLong xs = length' xs > 15
```

I made it a unary function so it can work with any list, not just `[1..100]`.

Comment: composed and combined are the same yes?  I wrot step by step because I want write my own filter function too. and not use prelude function to understand it.

Comment: How it call in winGHCi this?  combined = length' . collatz

Comment: Yes, they are the same, I fixed this typo. In GHCi, you can first define the function as written above and then apply it, e.g. `composed 5`.

Comment: FYI the parenthesis here are optional and removing them makes the line a bit easier to read imo.

Comment: @Memo, I omitted type signature contexts in my answer at first, but if you have `(Integral a)` in `collatz` then you need it even in `composed`. I have now added contexts to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `length'` of the `collatz` sequence for `n` is `\n -> length' (collatz n)`. This pattern is so common that we gave it a name: `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`. We call this "function composition". Replacing `f`, `g`, and `x` above with `length'`, `collatz`, and `n`, we get `length' . collatz = \n -> length' (collatz n)`. So:

```
collatzLength = length' . collatz
```

As an aside, instead of writing `isLong` as you do, we can use function composition here too, albeit in a slightly less obvious way:

```
isLong xs = length' xs > 15
isLong = \xs -> length' xs > 15
isLong = \xs -> (>) (length' xs) 15
isLong = \xs -> (> 15) (length' xs) -- this is the less obvious bit
isLong = (> 15) . length'
```

So the question "is the collatz sequence for the number n longer than 15?" can now be written as:

```
isLongSequence = isLong . collatz
```

So the long sequences for the numbers `[1..100]` are

```
filter isLongSequence [1..100]
```

or with

```
longSequences = filter isLongSequence
```

it's

```
longSequences [1..100]
```

now, we can write `numLongChains` as

```
numLongChains = length' . longSequences
```

The number of long chains is the number (length) of (the list of) long sequences.

Now, to show that this is equivalent to your definition, you need to know a rule (theorem) about map and filter:

```
filter p . map f = filter (p . f)
```

So

```
\xs -> filter isLong (map collatz xs)
```

is the same as

```
filter isLong . map collatz
```

is the same as

```
filter (isLong . collatz)
```

is the same as

```
filter isLongSequence
```

is the same as

```
longSequences
```